# center several blocks (titre, texte, logo)

Tags: css

I would like to get this result below:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qURJZ.png)

My problem is that, I don't understand why my blocks are not centered correctly even with the propriety `display: inline-block` in my selector `homebotblock1`?

I tried this:

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.homebot{
 background:url('https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/9zj3.jpg') no-repeat center;
 background-size:cover;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 min-height:500px;
 display:inline-block
 width:100%;
}

.homebotbg{
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 min-height:500px;
 display:block;
 width:43%;
 float:right;
 padding:100px 50px 50px 30px;
 text-shadow:#fff 1px 1px 0px;
 text-align:left;
}

.homebottit{
 font-size:24pt;
 font-family:roboto;color:#c22312;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin-bottom:50px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.homebotpad{
 padding-left:10px;
}

.homebottxt1{
 font-size:16pt;
 font-family:roboto;
 color:#000;
}

.homebottxt2{
 font-size:10pt;
 font-family:open sans2;
 color:#000;
}

.homebotblock1{
 width:80px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.homebotblock2{
 width:450px;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Titre de la page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="homebot">
  <div class="homebotbg">
   <span class="homebottit">Security Investment Solutions</span>
   <img class="homebotblock1" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/yljn.png" alt="img" />
   <div class="homebottxt1">ADVANTAGEOUS CONDITIONS</div>
    <div class="homebottxt2">We use your money to make a source of long-term profit. At the same time you become both our client and a shareholder.</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the `homebottxt1` and `homebottxt2` text in its own `<div>` then wrap that `<div>` and the image in another `<div>` with the class `homebotblock3`.

Then add this CSS:

```
.homebotblock3 {
  display: flex;
}

.homebotblock3 > div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

### Modified Code

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/gefhov6b/

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.homebot {
  background: url('https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/9zj3.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: inline-block width:100%;
}

.homebotbg {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  min-height: 500px;
  display: block;
  width: 43%;
  float: right;
  padding: 100px 50px 50px 30px;
  text-shadow: #fff 1px 1px 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

.homebottit {
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-family: roboto;
  color: #c22312;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.homebotpad {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.homebottxt1 {
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-family: roboto;
  color: #000;
}

.homebottxt2 {
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-family: open sans2;
  color: #000;
}

.homebotblock1 {
  width: 80px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.homebotblock2 {
  width: 450px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.homebotblock3 {
  display: flex;
}

.homebotblock3>div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titre de la page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="homebot">
    <div class="homebotbg">
      <span class="homebottit">Security Investment Solutions</span>
      <div class="homebotblock3">
        <img class="homebotblock1" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/yljn.png" alt="img" />
        <div>
          <div class="homebottxt1">ADVANTAGEOUS CONDITIONS</div>
          <div class="homebottxt2">We use your money to make a source of long-term profit. At the same time you become both our client and a shareholder.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are applying `inline-block` to the image separately, it is not horizontally aligning the image to any other element in the page.

To achieve your result, you will need to create a `div` structure that suits your needs and then apply your property.

Also, use `flex` instead of `inline-block`, it's much powerful. I have modified your code to achieve your result.

P.S. Kindly add in a `padding` as per your need. Since it is not the objective of the question, I have not included it in my answer.

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.homebot{
 background:url('https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/9zj3.jpg') no-repeat center;
 background-size:cover;
 background-attachment:fixed;
 min-height:500px;
 display:inline-block
 width:100%;
}

.homebotbg{
 background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 min-height:500px;
 display:block;
 width:43%;
 float:right;
 padding:100px 50px 50px 30px;
 text-shadow:#fff 1px 1px 0px;
 text-align:left;
}

.homebottit{
 font-size:24pt;
 font-family:roboto;color:#c22312;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 margin-bottom:50px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.homebotpad{
 padding-left:10px;
}

.homebottxt1{
 font-size:16pt;
 font-family:roboto;
 color:#000;
}

.homebottxt2{
 font-size:10pt;
 font-family:open sans2;
 color:#000;
}

.block{
  display: flex;
}

.homebotblock1{
 width:80px;
 display:inline-block;
}

.homebotblock2{
 width:450px;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Titre de la page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="homebot">
  <div class="homebotbg">
   <span class="homebottit">Security Investment Solutions</span>
    <div class="block">
      <img class="homebotblock1" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/yljn.png" alt="img" />
      <div>
        <div class="homebottxt1">ADVANTAGEOUS CONDITIONS</div>
        <div class="homebottxt2">We use your money to make a source of long-term profit. At the same time you become both our client and a shareholder.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.homebot{
 background: url('https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/9zj3.jpg');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: -100px;
  height: 25vw;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.homebotbg {
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  padding: 10px 30px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

.homebot-header {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.homebottit {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.homebot-footer {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.homebotblock1 {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.homebottxt1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Titre de la page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="homebot">
      <div class="homebotbg">
        <div class="homebot-header">
          <p class="homebottit">Security Investment Solutions</p>
        </div>
        <div class="homebot-footer">
          <img class="homebotblock1" src="https://zupimages.net/up/20/21/yljn.png" alt="img" />
          <div class="homebot-footer-right">
            <p class="homebottxt1">ADVANTAGEOUS CONDITIONS</p>
            <p class="homebottxt2">We use your money to make a source of long-term profit. At the same time you become both our client and a shareholder.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can design like this.
The key point here is to use `flex layout`.
Using flex layout by `display: flex`, you can make this structure easily.